# SearchVIew in android

Tags: android, xml, searchview

In my app I have a SearchView. What I need to do is to get the text that the user types in the search view. Then I need to send a request to the server to make the search for me and give the results of this search.The result is an XML file.  Finally I need to display these results to the user. How can I do that? I know how to do the final part of the job where I display the results to the user. But i do not know how to do the other part of the job. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just get the value of text from EditText that user types through "yourEditText.getText().toString()" and then append this value to your request to be send to server.

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html